# What is the functionality of Public->index.html in cypress and do we need to push it to git/github?

Tags: html, node.js, github, cypress, element

In my framework, I have public->index.html where I have the below elements.
I got a couple of questions:

1. What is the functionality of this js file?
2. Do I need to push it to GIT/GITHUB

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Five Minutes of HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cypress Cookies</h1>
    <button id="clicked">
        Click to generate cookies
    </button>
    <h2>Various Inputs</h2>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="normal-text">Normal Text Input</label>
            <input type="text" name="normal-text" id="normal-text">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="key-combo">Key Combination Input</label>
            <input type="text" name="key-combo" id="key-combo">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="date">Date Input</label>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="month">Month Input</label>
            <input type="month" name="month" id="month">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="week">Week Input</label>
            <input type="week" name="week" id="week">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <label for="time">Time Input</label>
            <input type="time" name="time" id="time">
        </div>
.....
```

Comment: If your file doesn't contain the sensible information of your site then you can push it to git/GitHub.

Comment: so, what is the usage of this index.html file? Why do we have it?

Comment: Does that fille live in your cypress folder ? This file is not included when adding cypress to your project.  I dont think I have ever seen it before...

Comment: yes, under cypress there is public folder and under public folder we have index.html

Comment: How did you add cypress to your project ? If you dont use it im sure you can delete it. There is no reason for that file being there, its just a view. I have a few projects that I added cypress to and I have never seen that before.